# Android upgrading a DB with a NOT NULL column - what happens to old users

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app released in app store
I want to add a new column to the user table in the sqlite db and want it to be not null
But I also want old users to be able to use the app

What will happen if an old user updates their app with the new version? At login, I get the info from the server and I insert it in the db. The db insertion will probably stop when there is no value for the new column

Also, how do I do the upgrade itself?

- in onUpgrade I do "ALTER table USER..."
- in the constructor of the SQLite helper I add the new DB version

what else?

Also, I've added 3-4 totally new tables needed for new features. I've called their create queries in the onCreate method of the SQLite helper. Should I do anything else in addition to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in the constructor of the SQLite helper I add the new DB version

That will trigger `onUpgrade()`, good.

However, you cannot use `ALTER TABLE` to add a column with `NOT NULL`.

Here's what you can do in `onUpgrade()` to preserve user data:

- Rename the old table to a temporary name
- Recreate the table with the new column and `NOT NULL`
- Populate the new table from the old temp table and supply the new column a reasonable non-null default value
- Drop the temporary table

> Can you give me an example lets say table is called USER with fields NAME and EMAIL and now I want to add a new field AGE?

Here's an example:

```
sqlite> create table user(name, email);
sqlite> insert into user select 'foo','bar';
sqlite> alter table user rename to user_temp;
sqlite> create table user(name, email, age not null);
sqlite> insert into user select name,email,-1 from user_temp;
sqlite> drop table user_temp;
sqlite> select * from user;
name|email|age
foo|bar|-1
```

> Also, I've added 3-4 totally new tables needed for new features. I've called their create queries in the onCreate method of the SQLite helper. Should I do anything else in addition to this?
>
> should I put the new creates for the new tables in both onCreate and onUpgrade or only in onUpgrade?

Make sure the same new tables are created in `onUpgrade()`.

`onCreate()` is only run when the database is created for the first time, not on upgrade.

After both `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` the database schema (table structure) should be compatible. *How* you implement it is up to you. Putting the `CREATE TABLE`s there in `onUpgrade()` is an option. Some people prefer to call `onCreate()` insinde `onUpgrade()`, which can cause some headache when trying to migrate old data.

Comment: Hey thanks, I did not at all expect for it to be that more complicated. Can you give me an example lets say table is called USER with fields NAME and EMAIL and now I want to add a new field AGE?

Comment: should I put the new creates for the new tables in both onCreate and onUpgrade or only in onUpgrade?

Comment: so I add them to both methods?

Comment: So you advice against dropping all tables and creating them anew? This would erase all of the user's data, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the consequence of dropping. If the data is throw-away, then feel free to drop. If the data is important, take steps to retain it.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything you taught me today!